# add custom attribute to a view in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-attributes

I have a library wich create a customViewGroup and do something fancy with them, by default you can use this VIEWGROUP in XML and add any child you want to it like this.

```
<CustomFancyViewGroup
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:cusattr="15dp"/>

<CustomFancyViewGroup/>
```

and this work fine except if you want to add a child programmatically .
I cannot find anyway to set "cusattr" to a view programmatically.
so is there any way to add custom Attribute  to a view programmatically?

Comment: Are you asking how to write something in the `CustomFancyViewGroup` class to allow you to add a `View` like this?

Comment: no hole point is that I don't want to change CustomFancyViewGroup I only want to add a view programmatically to CustomFancyViewGroup wich contain "app:cusattr".

Comment: Then it depends on `CustomFancyViewGroup`. Does it have any public methods to do what you're asking? Either to add a child with that attribute, or to set that attribute on a child? Does it have its own `LayoutParams` that handle that attribute? How does it handle that attribute? There is no generic answer for this.

Comment: nice hint man thanks actually it does have a customLayout params.